# Herbivorous plants that consume falling leaves

Tags: botany

I've just seen a report about specialized herbivorous plants which build special traps to catch falling leaves from trees above them.

The only thing, which I'm missing is the correct name of this plant. Do you have any idea what plant(s) could this be?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Did you try to go through the [wikipedia list of carnivorous plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_carnivorous_plants)?

Comment: You seem to misuse either of the term 'carnivorous' or 'vegetarian' in your title! You should have a look at the wikipedia entries for [vegetarinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarianism) or [carnivores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnivore)

Comment: The term "herbivorous" plants would be a more accurate description of the plants that you are asking about.

Comment: You say you're missing the 'correct' name of the plant - does that mean the report gives an 'incorrect' (common) name for it? If so, could you post it?

Comment: Some bromelias growing up in the trees in tropical rainforests catch falling rainwater and probably leaves to extract nutriens. See [here](http://www.asknature.org/strategy/5c3f3f250731561714d60f47585eba0e). Is that what you mean?

Comment: @RHA: Note that Bromeliaceae only grow in South American rainforests. They do not occur in Asian and African rainforests.

Comment: If you've "just" read that "report", maybe in newspaper or magazine etc, you could provide some more specific information, such as if they've provided any common-name, locality, botanic garden(sometimes) or any-other specific features. Plant kingdom is very huge, and a "report" usually is something not-popular or not well-known (otherwise it will not be reported). So the information provided here,  does-not lead to a specific direction.

Comment: Most plant utilize the rotten, humic matter in the forest floor. Rotting  (biodegradation) of fallen leaves, twigs etc. is a key source of  nutrients (manure) in soil, and it is an way of re-use of atoms.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Well I would like to provide more information. But I've seen these documentation on a flight, and I just woke up a few minutes before this part of the documentation has been shown. Due to this fact, I couldn't provide much more information. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I found the answer myself.

The special plant I'm looking for is the [Nepenthes ampullaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepenthes_ampullaria). It has developed away from the "normal" carnivorous plants to a more [detritivorous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detritivore) species.

Nepenthes ampullaria has specialized her pitcher to catch falling leaves from trees above her.

Answer (score 2):

Many plants do this, with varying degrees of specialization - for some it is perhaps incidental, others have evolved this strategy to gain nutrients (often water as well). You are probably thinking of [bromeliads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromeliaceae), a diverse group of plants in which many species have specialized leaves that form cups at the base to collect water and litter. These structures, a type of [phytotelmata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytotelma), have similarities to some carnivorous plant traps.

These tank bromeliads are able to [efficiently absorb nutrients from animal or plant matter which falls into the tank](http://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/336508):

> Considerable absorbed nitrogen is mobilized in the rosette center. Tested bromeliads appear to be well equipped to utilize minerals and organic nitrogen originating from tank-impounded plant and animal debris as nutrients.

This litter catching habit occurs in other lithophytic and epiphytic plants, i.e. those which don't grow in soil, because it allows them to capture nutrients when growing on rocks or trees. Examples include the [staghorns/elkhorns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platycerium) and [basket ferns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drynaria):

> They form a characteristic 'basket' that collect litter and organic debris, hence the common name. The collected debris decompose into humus, providing the plants with nutrients it would otherwise not have received from being suspended above the ground.

Comment: Thank you @nicfit! But it's not a bromeliads plant. I have them on my own in my home. But the plant I've seen was definitely no bromeliads. But thanks to your post, I've found the real plant I'm looking for. Thanks a lot.